# Serving a front end created with create-react-app with Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, create-react-app

I have a Flask back-end with API routes which are accessed by a React single page application created using create-react-app. When using the create-react-app dev server, my Flask back end works.

I would like to serve the built (using `npm run build`) static React app from my Flask server. Building the React app leads to the following directory structure:

```
- build
  - static
    - css
        - style.[crypto].css
        - style.[crypto].css.map
    - js
        - main.[crypto].js
        - main.[crypto].js.map
  - index.html
  - service-worker.js
  - [more meta files]
```

By `[crypto]`, I mean the randomly generated strings generated at build time.

Having received the `index.html` file, the browser then makes the following requests:

```
- GET /static/css/main.[crypto].css
- GET /static/css/main.[crypto].css
- GET /service-worker.js
```

How should I serve these files? I came up with this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, send_from_directory

static = Blueprint('static', __name__)

@static.route('/')
def serve_static_index():
    return send_from_directory('../client/build/', 'index.html')

@static.route('/static/<path:path>') # serve whatever the client requested in the static folder
def serve_static(path):
    return send_from_directory('../client/build/static/', path)

@static.route('/service-worker.js')
def serve_worker():
    return send_from_directory('../client/build/', 'service-worker.js')
```

This way, the static assets are successfully served.

On the other hand, I could incorporate this with the built-in Flask static utilities. But I do not understand how to configure this.

Is my solution robust enough? Is there a way to use built-in Flask features to serve these assets? Is there a better way to use create-react-app?

Comment: flask should know about your static folder without you having to do anything (as long as the folder is named static and is next to your flask entrypoint) ... ie `cp -rf /build/static ./static` as part of your build script ...

Comment: you can also use nginx to serve your static files, which is usually the recommended via (nginx is super good for static files)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='react_app/build')

# Serve React App
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path != "" and os.path.exists(app.static_folder + '/' + path):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, port=5000, threaded=True)
```

Thats what I ended up with. So bascially catch all routes, test if the path is a file => send file => else send the index.html. That way you can reload the react app from any route you wish and it does not break.

Comment: I'm getting mime type errors with this solution :-(
`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). /service-worker.js 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
registerServiceWorker.js:71 
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

Comment: @user3216673 it most likely is not an issue with flask or create-react-app but with your Browser. A guess in the wild: unregister your service workers might resolve the issue.

Comment: You can use app.static_folder to keep your code DRY

Comment: In case you want to serve the app from a sub-path, instead of the root. (like in my case) 

You can do 
`@app.route('/app', defaults={'path': ''}) @app.route('/app/<path:path>')`

and then in your CRA app `package.json` add `homepage: "./app"`

Comment: Works, altough no full idea of what's  going on heehe

Comment: how would one do this with next.js?

Comment: thank you, `send_from_directory` is the one - using it all in a slightly different way: `render_template('index.html')` for `\ ` and `def catch_all(path)` (similarly to Flask docs [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/singlepageapplications/)) with that perfect `send_from_directory`, then I'll catch the errors and check `path`s for the needed API calls (that's why I use Flask after all)

Answer (score 23):

A working solution here. 
Ever thought why we need two separate folders for `static` and `templates`. To segregate the mess, right? 
But, it's a problem with the production build since it has one folder for both `static` and `templates` type of files and all dependencies are linked like that.

The `build` folder will be served if you consider it both `static` and `templates`.

Use something like this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='',
                  static_folder='build',
                  template_folder='build')

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Your flask app will run fine.

Comment: This answer saved me. All the others had some caveats that didn't fit my setup.

Comment: That `static_url_path=''` is what made it work for me.

Answer (score 19):

First do `npm run build` to build the static production files as mentioned by you above

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="build/static", template_folder="build")

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

print('Starting Flask!')

app.debug=True
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get it work with the development hot-reload.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer does not work for me. I have used

```py
import os

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, jsonify, render_template, request

from server.landing import landing as landing_bp
from server.api import api as api_bp

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../client/build")
app.register_blueprint(landing_bp, url_prefix="/landing")
app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix="/api/v1")


@app.route("/")
def serve():
    """serves React App"""
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, "index.html")


@app.route("/<path:path>")
def static_proxy(path):
    """static folder serve"""
    file_name = path.split("/")[-1]
    dir_name = os.path.join(app.static_folder, "/".join(path.split("/")[:-1]))
    return send_from_directory(dir_name, file_name)


@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_404(e):
    if request.path.startswith("/api/"):
        return jsonify(message="Resource not found"), 404
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, "index.html")


@app.errorhandler(405)
def handle_405(e):
    if request.path.startswith("/api/"):
        return jsonify(message="Mehtod not allowed"), 405
    return e
```

Comment: Worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

I used a flask server with only one **route /** which read the index.html file from the build folder of Create react app(CRA)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder =  '../build'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    fref = open(r'../build/index.html')
    html_text = fref.read()
    fref.close()
    return html_text

app.run()
```

Setting up this way I faced an error, the static files are not properly served due to path mismatch, **so the solution I used is**

1. Add a homepage property in package.json of CRA and set it to **"/static"**

> {
> "name":"App-name",
> "version":"",
> "dependencies":{}
> "homepage":"/static",....[other keys]}

```
 Add **homepage** key parallel to the **dependencies** key in the package.json file
```

2. This **homepage** property will be used during the build process of CRA and used in the place of  %PUBLIC_URL% of index.html and gets appended to other static assets URL path (you can verify by viewing the index.html code after the build process)
3. After the build process, run the flask server,we can see the GET request coming with **/** for the first time and **index.html** will be served and followed by requests **/static/static/js/[[filename]]** for other static assets from HTML file and everything works correctly