# Adding React app to Flask under URL prefix

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, routes

I have a React app that I want to reside on a specific url route prefix of a Flask app.

Examples:

- `host.com/` is the home page of the Flask app. It's `index.html` file in the `templates` directory (using standard Flask conventions here).
- `host.com/about` is another page of the Flask app. It's some other file in the same `templates` directory.
- `host.com/search` is the root of the React app. I want anything with `/search` prefix to reference some part of the React app.
- `host.com/search/123` is some page of the React app (following the above logic). I am using `react-router-dom` for routing inside React app.

I built the React app with `npm run build` and then tried serving just the React app with Flask like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-create-react-app-with-flask/45634550). Everything worked fine.

Then I attempted the following to put React at specific url prefix of the Flask app:

```
# file app.py

import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from .search_blueprint import search_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(search_blueprint, url_prefix='/search')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, port=5000, threaded=True)
```

And here are the contents of the `search_blueprint.py` file (very similar to the answer to the question that I [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-create-react-app-with-flask/45634550):

```
# file search_blueprint.py

from flask import Blueprint, send_from_directory
import os

build_dir = os.path.abspath('./app/static/build')
search_blueprint = Blueprint('search', __name__, static_folder=build_dir)

# Serve React App
@search_blueprint.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@search_blueprint.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if(path == ""):
        return send_from_directory(build_dir, 'index.html')
    else:
        if(os.path.exists(os.path.join(build_dir, path))):
            return send_from_directory(build_dir, path)
        else:
            return send_from_directory(build_dir, 'index.html')
```

The Flask `index.html` page that is referenced in `app.py` loads fine when I go to `host.com/`. When I go to `host.com/search` I get a blank screen (meaning no errors from Flask). In the console there's an error message like this:

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://host.com/static/js/main.ca656ef1.js”.`

Anyone knows why I can't get this React app work at a specified url prefix?

Here's the directory layout relevant to the question:

```
app
├───static
│    └───build
├───templates
│    └───index.html
├───app.py
└───search_blueprint.py
```

#### Edit

Adding contents of `build` directory:

```
build
│   asset-manifest.json
│   favicon.ico
│   index.html
│   manifest.json
│   service-worker.js
│
└───static
    ├───css
    │       main.d293ea0a.css
    │       main.d293ea0a.css.map
    │
    ├───js
    │       main.ca656ef1.js
    │       main.ca656ef1.js.map
    │
    └───media
            logo.5d5d9eef.svg
```

Comment: From your directory layout, your js `<script>` source should be `http://host.com/static/build/main.ca656ef1.js` but it's `http://host.com/static/js/main.ca656ef1.js`. What is in the build folder? Are you using webpack? How are the scripts being added to your index.html page?

Comment: Not using webpack. React app was created using `create-react-app` and fully resides within `static` directory. Not sure how exactly scripts are added but when following answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-create-react-app-with-flask/45634550) to serve just the React app with Flask, everything works. I am simply moving that logic to a Blueprint to try to move the app under a specified url prefix. I added contents of `build` directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='app/static/build')
```

You have to specify that static directory when you create the Flask app.
This was driving me insane so I hope it helps you and others.

Cheers