# How to run React javascript in Flask server?

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, flask

I have a server in Flask and I try created PWA with React. I am totally new in web development.
I created a Flask server, REST api too and something like a react projects but when I tried create something for front-end its not working. In my opinion file index.html have not included React.

This is my server.py:

```
api = Api(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("roos/public/index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='8080')
```

I run server with command: python server.py
And it's works - when I use webbrowser -> 127.0.0.0:8080 I have a white page

This is works.

In roos I have this directories, with files:

```
-ROOS
|-node_modules
 |-(many hundred directory)
|-public
 |- favicon.ico
 |- index.html
 |-manifest.json
|-src
 |-App.css
 |-App.js
 |-App.test.js
 |-index.css
 |-index.js
 |-logo.svg
 |-serviceWorker.js
-package.json
-package-lock.json
```

My file, index.html look like:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>ROOS</title>
 </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And file index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And this not working - I can't run any scripts which I created in this file. In my opinion index.js is not call when I run the server. I don't have idea how I can start this .js scripts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serving a create-react-app with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-create-react-app-with-flask)

Comment: @ShrimpPhaser unfourtanelly this themat don't help me. I totally not understand what happen in this thema