# Is it possible to integrate a graphic interface into a web page in my flask app?

Tags: python, flask, tkinter

I'm creating a web app with flask, this app works with a graphic interactive interface with user.

The user gives input data and the program displays results and some graphs.
My interface works as I wanted,

The question is:

> How can I make the interface as one of my web pages and not an executable window that appears separately?

I hope it's clear.

```
import Main             #file containing the graphic interface code
from flask import Flask,request, render_template
from time import localtime, sleep


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/interface')
def web():
    M=Main.Generale()      #instantiated my class
    return render_template('web.html',M=M)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you aware of the concept called "the web"? If so, you can make a graphical user interface using HTML and CSS

Comment: desktop app and web pages works different - web server sends HTML, images or SVG to client which displays it but desktop app draw widgets directly to screen, doesn't create image which you could catch and send to client. And desktop in different way communicate between widgets - it has access all time. Web page sends page and forget client - client has to use cookies (session ID) to informat server who is connected at this moment. Better convert GUI to web page, eventually to text script which you can run from Flask - but it may also not works as you expect.

Comment: Are you aware that we can build web apps with python? SURPRISE? and we can also program GUI with python's tkinter package!

Comment: @furas thank you so much! it is actually a concept of a web app

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't integrate a Tk/Tkinter GUI into a web page. (Not without some very significant advanced magic á la Emscripten, anyway.)

You'll have to look into web frontend programming (JavaScript) to reimplement the UI you have if you want it to be used over the web.

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off creating an interface with something like React that makes request to your Flask backend. You can build the React project and serve the static files from Flask.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-create-react-app-with-flask)