# Serving React static build files from Flask blueprint fails with 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, flask, url, create-react-app

I'm developing a Flask API and a React SPA to consume it. I'm also trying to serve the front-end static files from Flask: I'm aware that serving static files from Flask isn't the best idea, however since this deployment is just for reviewing the project from Heroku, I decided to serve them from Flask.

I created a Blueprint called `static_resource_bp` to return the static files, [following the advice in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209978/serving-a-front-end-created-with-create-react-app-with-flask):

```py
#__init__.py for the static file blueprint
import pdb

from flask import Blueprint
from flask.helpers import send_from_directory

static_resource_bp = Blueprint(
    "static_resource", __name__, static_folder="static"
)


@static_resource_bp.route("/")
def serve_index():
    return send_from_directory(static_resource_bp.static_folder, "index.html")


# This route isn't even being hit by the client request
@static_resource_bp.route("/static/<path>")
def serve_static(path):
    pdb.set_trace()
    return send_from_directory(static_resource_bp.static_folder, path)
```

As far as I can tell, the `static` folder is properly registered with the `static_resource_bp`, as it can return the `index.html` file. But when it comes to returning the other files, the second route **is not being requested by my browser**, as I can see in my Flask console that `pdb.set_trace()` isn't stopping the application as it should. These are the errors returned:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:45:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:45:19] "GET /static/js/main.98438330.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:45:19] "GET /static/css/main.5289cea3.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:45:19] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2022 09:45:19] "GET /logo192.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

This is the folder structure of my `static_resource_bp` blueprint. Its `static` folder contains the build files from my React application to simplify the routes.

```
>>> tree .
.
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
└── static
    ├── asset-manifest.json
    ├── index.html
    ├── manifest.json
    └── static
        ├── css
        │   ├── main.5289cea3.css
        │   └── main.5289cea3.css.map
        └── js
            ├── main.98438330.js
            ├── main.98438330.js.LICENSE.txt
            └── main.98438330.js.map

5 directories, 10 files
```

Furthermore, as far as I can tell the `static_resource_bp` is correctly registered with my application factory, `__init__.py`:

```py
# In '__init__.py, my application factory:

def create_app(config_name):
    # Initialize and configure application
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
    
    # Extension initializations here...
    
    # Blueprint initializations. 
    from .api import api_bp

    app.register_blueprint(api_bp)

    from .static_route import static_resource_bp

    app.register_blueprint(static_resource_bp)

    return app
```

At this point I believe it might be an error with the URLs, but I can't figure out where I made the mistake. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Could your two static folders be causing a problem? Would it work to simply have the 'css' and 'js' folders directly in the first static folder?

Comment: @PatrickYoder, not precisely, but your comment pointed me to the right direction and ultimately solved the issue. The issue wasn't Flask (thanks god), it was the URLs being used by the `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the `index.html` file. Modifying them made the application work. Thanks!

Comment: Another solution would be not using Flask blueprints. I'm not sure why, but that got rid of my 404 error. This comment is beyond the scope of the question, but that's always good to know if your application doesn't strictly need blueprints.